# JAVAFX8 updating controls models?

Tags: multithreading, javafx-8

UI Control such as LISTVIEW or Tree or ... comes with model that is observable.

When one make a change to that model, I suppose JavaFX knows how to refresh it automatically in the display.

However my question here is as follows:

Is it the intent way, that someone who wants to update and not replace this model, do so in a background thread with a platform.runlater.

In other words, one has some serious computation to do, and needs to to update an ObservableList as a result. Is it the intended way, to do the heavy work in a background thread and at the end of it, run the update in a platform run later?

I'm asking this because this is what I have been doing so far without problem. But from my reading here and there, in particular in

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html

It seems that some other mechanism shall be used. One should rather return a full list instead of updating the observable list.

But this works only if things comes from the GUI. In case the update is triggered from the back end, there is no way to do so.

The solution that I have used so far, was always to hold a reference to the observable list and updating it by means of platform.Runlater.

Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you give has an example (the `PartialResultsTask`) that does as you describe: it updates an existing `ObservableList` as it progresses via a call to `Platform.runLater()`. So this is clearly a supported way of doing things.

For updating from the back end (i.e. from a class unaware that the data are being used in a UI), you'd really have to post some code for anyone to be able to help. But you might have a look at the techniques used in [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javafxinteg-2062777.html). While he doesn't actually update lists from the backend in the examples there, the same strategy could be used to do so.

Comment: So far to update from the back end i never had any issue. I just warp obersableList in something that i call a service for that object and which provide method that call the platform runlater. Although this service class only provide batch method such as addAll, to avoid creating too much runnables. I'll check your example

Comment: Oh i see it's a bit more elaborate thanks. Lot of good idea. For that matter i'm although more incline to use actors. I asked here a few month ago about how to integrate Akka and Javafx2. The solution is way easier once set up